# Images in content type: reusing and limit

Tags: media

In a content type template, I allow images. The only widget that appears for that field, is a File Upload widget. What if I want to reuse the image that has already been uploaded?

Also, how do I raise the limit of uploaded images from 10 to more?

Thanks
Artur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) module to allow you to select new or existing files through additional means, including:

1. Re-use files by an auto-complete textfield
2. Attach server-side files uploaded via FTP
3. Transfer files from a remote server (cURL required)

**4. Select existing files through the IMCE file browser**

Also, to raise the limit of uploaded images from 10 to more, edit your image field settings and set the "Number of values" to "unlimited"